# Display HREF links on page in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I would like to replace or append text in h2 tag with href link from previous links with some greasemonkey script. For example, I have ten of these links:

```
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link1.com">SomeLinkText1</a></div>
<h2 class="legend">Some text 1</h2>
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link2.com">SomeLinkText2</a></div>
<h2 class="legend">Some text 2</h2>
...
```

I need it to be:

```
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link1.com">SomeLinkText1</a></div>
<h2 class="legend">Some text 1 - www.link1.com</h2>
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link2.com">SomeLinkText2</a></div>
<h2 class="legend">Some text 2 - www.link2.com</h2>
...
```

So, I just want to extract all hrefs on the page and display them bellow in h2 or some new div (it doesn't matter where, it could be also INSTEAD of SomeLinkText in the same a tag) - for example:

```
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link1.com">www.link1.com</a></div>
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link2.com">www.link2.com</a></div>
...
```

I'm very weak with javascript. I used search here and I found some answer but it works only for first link.

```
$('.legend').html($('.cml a').prop('href'));
```

Can someone help me with code so I can display href on the page dinamically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Can use [`text(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) which will loop over each instance. Inside the function `this` is the current element instance and you use that to traverse to previous element to get the corresponding href

```js
$('.legend').text(function(index, currText) {
  var linkUrl = $(this).prev('.cml').find('a').attr('href');
  return currText + ' - ' + linkUrl;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link1.com">SomeLinkText1</a></div>
<h2 class="legend">Some text 1</h2>
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link2.com">SomeLinkText2</a></div>
<h2 class="legend">Some text 2</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can loop over `a` and append the text to the next `h2` of parent `cim` like

```js
$('a').each(function(){
  $(this).closest(".cml").next().text($(this).closest(".cml").next().text() + " - "+$(this).attr("href"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link1.com">SomeLinkText1</a></div>
<h2 class="legend">Some text 1</h2>
<div class="cml">This is some <a href="www.link2.com">SomeLinkText2</a></div>
<h2 class="legend">Some text 2</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each function of jquery to iterate each cml class and append the required text to h2

```
$(".cml").each(function(){
     var linkToAppend = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
     $(this).next().append(" - " + linkToAppend);
});
```